# .htaccess to web.config issue

Tags: .htaccess, web-config

I shifted my website from Linux server to windows virtual server. 
I am facing an issue with the .htaccess file.

I converted the .htaccess to web.config but it's not working the way like .htaccss was working on Linux server

**HTACCESS CODE:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

WEB CONFIG CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="rule 1h" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^"  />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/-"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2h" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^"  />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html"  />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My website is in angular universal so this code is highly needed for that.

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
            <rules>
              <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </rewrite>
          <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
              <profiles>
                  <add extension=".js" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
              </profiles>
          </caching>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```